# How to make react router, change what file is rendering based on the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've been working with react router and its been giving me nothing but trouble. I want a button to load a new page, what I would like is to have a class to switch the file its rendering based on the link. I could be using the wrong thing but so any nudge in the right direction would be great.

here are my 3 main files

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import RouteFile from './RouteFile';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouteFile />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

RoutFile.js

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import App from './App';
import Create from './Create';
function RouteFile() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" children={<App />}/>
                <Route path="/create" children={<Create />}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
export default RouteFile;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App background">
        <div className="container">
          <li>
            <Link className="button a" to="/create"><div className="button-container"><div className="icon new"></div><div className="text new-text">Create</div></div></Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className="button a" to="/open">Open</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className="button a" to="/explore">Explore</Link>
          </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. With the `Switch` component route order and specificity matter. "/" is a less specific path than "/create" and will be matched and rendered first.
2. You need only one `Router` in your app to provide the routing context for all nested route, switch, and link components.

## Solution

1. Order more specific paths before less specific paths in `RouteFile`.

   ```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/create" children={<Create />}/>
        <Route path="/" children={<App />}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
   ```
2. Remove the `Router` wrapping your links in `App`.

   ```
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App background">
            <div className="container">
              <li>
                <Link className="button a" to="/create">
                  <div className="button-container">
                    <div className="icon new"></div>
                    <div className="text new-text">Create</div>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link className="button a" to="/open">Open</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link className="button a" to="/explore">Explore</Link>
              </li>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
   ```

Comment: This worked! thank you. Honestly I didn't think it would be that simple.